# Obtener numero luego del strong

Tags: java, jsoup

Estoy comenzando la libreria de Jsoup, me gustaria que me ayudaran a extraer el texto que se encuentra luego del strong del siguiente codigo fuente:

```
</div>    
          <div id="dolar" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">        
    <div class="field-content">
        <div class="row recuadrotsmc">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <img src="/sites/default/files/dollar-04_2.png" class="icono_bss_blanco1">      
                <span> USD</span>    </div>
                          
                         <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 centrado"><strong> 27,27800000 </strong> </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

Ya logre obtener el documento, el problema viene es con la obtencion del dato

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda que es importante agregar lo que trataste, revisar [ask], saludos.